# When to rebuild ssas aggregation designs?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

We have an "age" dimension in our SSAS Cube.  It's basically just the one attribute that's the person's whole number age at the time an event happened.  We've had a requirement to further break it down into adult/child with a sub group of adult/geriatric and pediatric/neonatal.

When adding these new attributes to the dimension and a hierarchy, do I have to go into the aggregation designs and rebuild the ones that reference the dimension?

We aren't changing the key of the patient age, just adding the extra data.

Comment: Aggregations make queries faster. If users do not complain about query performance then I would not create aggregations

Comment: These tables have a few hundred million records in them, hence already having aggregations built.  I'm wanting to know if I modify a dimension, is it recommended that I rebuild the Aggregation design? or will deploying the cube detect the new attributes and include them in the aggregations when the Cube processes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you aggregations won't include new level automatically, but they will help anyway: engine can use lower than your new level aggregations of the same dimension as it's faster than retrieving from data files.

Please also remember '1/3 rule': aggregations should be less than 1/3 the size of the fact table.

You can see details in amazing white paper 'Analysis Services 2008 R2 Performance Guide' http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/6/6567C845-FC8D-4D62-920F-C027A349C889/SSASPerfGuide2008R2.pdf (3.4 Aggregations, page 60).